# Handle PayPal Smart Checkout Buttons with Laravel & ReactJS Frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, paypal

I am having some trouble thinking this through the right way.
I am running Laravel as the backend for a ReactJS Frontend - separately.

It is going to be a small onlineshop only having PayPal as the Payment Gateway (using PayPal Smart Checkout Buttons) without User Registration.

React will call the Laravel API on payment initiation which will prepare the actual call to PayPal on server-side *(get the price from database, in case user tampered with it, i take only the product ID and get the real product data from the database)*. The response will be returned to React.
As you might know PayPal works this way: **create order** in first API call, then **capture the order** in second API call ("create order" and "capture order" calls)

Laravel Endpoints that are called: "/create-paypal-transaction" and "/capture-paypal-transaction".

Currently *(old version of this project was a monolithic laravel solution, no separate frontend)* I store the response of the ***"capture order"*** API call in my DB as the final order / as the completed transaction. The result of the **"create order"** call is not stored in the DB. I do store the result of the **"create order"** call, with all its information (product, price, id, paypal_id etc.) in the session. Then, after capturing I load from the session to create the final order as a DB entry.

My trouble is: how do I securely realize this with a separate frontend and pass data from my first API call to my second API call?

I see only two options right now, maybe you guys can enlighten me:

1. Save the response from PayPal of the *"create order"-call* to my DB
   via laravel and then, after approval & response of the *"capture
   order"-call*, just update the stored order status from something
   like "created" to "captured".
2. Use the response data from the first API call in React and pass it to the second API call to hit the Laravel & store the order if PayPal returns success.

***Problems that I don't like with either method:***
currently there is no Authentication method implemented (no JWT or Passport or any). I was going to go with Laravel default API Authentication as I have no Users - therefore Passport & JWT don't seem to fit perfectly. People checkout without any registration. Therefore:
if I go with 1. solution people could easily mess with the DB and create loads of orders ***("create order" calls)***

and the 2. solution is just no real solution. I will not trust client-side data.

So, please, please let me know if you got any idea how to do this the smart way. Maybe I just don't see the obvious right now, but it has been a long day and all the thought about right way to securely communicate have been making me tired...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both (1) and (2) are overly complex. When the client calls `create-paypal-transaction`, all it needs in response (in addition to anything of your own you want to provide for your own purposes) is the order `id`. That's it, that's all the client wants and needs to keep track of.

It will use that `id` when it calls `capture-paypal-transaction`, and your webserver can check that it is appropriate and valid (in the session) before attempting to do the capture. No database storage is necessary until you have a successful capture, although you are welcome to store in-progress orderIDs for debug purposes.  They have no accounting value, and no security value outside the session.

Comment: Well I got some information (selected product, user input) to get to from the Frontend to my DB. How else would you do that?

Comment: The session, alongside the order `id`. Nothing needs to be in the DB until it's been paid for.

Comment: How do you know it really is the same "user", and not someone else? The session.